# MS Graph API protect Excel worksheet function with the range

Tags: excel, rest, http, graph

I want to stop others from editing the cell contents(ex: A4:H36) in my excel sheet using MS Graph API. Do I need to do two-step?

1. Set up the "Format Cells" as locked status used [MS Graph API VBA locked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.cellformat.locked)
2. Use [MS Graph API protect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/worksheetprotection-protect?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to activate the protection

But I don't know how to set the range of cells (ex: A4:H36) as "locked" by MS Graph API, like this:

1. POST .../workbook/worksheets('XXXX')/Range(address='A4:H36')/**locked**
2. POST .../workbook/worksheets('XXXX')/protection/protect

Did someone has experience with this? Thank you.

Regards,

ilu989

Comment: Are you looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect?

Comment: @BigBen , Thanks for your direction, I modify my question been more precisely, is it make sense?

Comment: Why are you trying to use the MS Graph API? You need the Excel API, right?

Comment: @BigBen, Because I'm working on the Flow design interact with SharePoint library, MS Graph API is what I know can used, Excel API can also work on this? I don't know, do you have any advice?

Comment: I'm not familiar (yet) with MS Graph, but from a quick read of that documentation I realize I may have misunderstood your question.

Comment: By the way, note that the first link is from the Excel object model.